# updateExistingPivot won't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot-table

I'm trying to update my pivot table **approve_document** where it has a extra column `isApprove` using `->withPivot` method.

Model:

Document

```
class Document extends Model
{
  public function sentToApprovers()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Approve', 'approve_document')->withPivot('isApprove');
  }
}
```

Approve

```
class Approve extends Model
{
  public function createdpendingDocuments()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'approve_document')->withPivot('isApprove');
  }
}
```

This is where I get all my records in my **approve_document**.

Controller:

```
public function documentsSentForApproval()
{
    $pendingDocumentLists = DB::table('approve_document')
    ->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'approve_document.dateReceived', 'documents.id', 'approves.approver_id')
    ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approve_document.document_id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
    ->join('approves', 'approves.id', '=', 'approve_document.approve_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approves.approver_id')
    ->where('approver_id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->orWhere('requestedBy', '=', Auth::id())
    ->get();


    return view ('document.pending')
    ->with('pendingDocumentLists', $pendingDocumentLists);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($pendingDocumentLists as $list)
    <tr class = "info">

        <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ strip_tags(substr($list->content, 0, 50)) }} {{ strlen($list->content) > 50 ? "..." : '' }}</td>
        <td>{{ $list->category_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
        <td>{{ date('M, j, Y', strtotime($list->dateReceived)) }}</td>
                    <td>

            @if (Auth::id() == $list->approver_id)

               <a href = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->id) }}">
                   <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> Approve</button>
                </a>

            @endif

        </td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

You can see here I have a approve button where I need to set `isApprove` to true when the button is clicked. You can see that I get the current id of the document when the button was clicked.

This part of the Controller where I'm having a hard time updating my pivot table. It gives me a error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Any tips or help would greatly appreciated!

```
public function updateIsApprove($id)
{
    $document = new Document();

    foreach ($document as $update)
    {
        $approve = new Approve();   

        $document->sentToApprovers()->updateExistingPivot([$approve->id => ['isApprove' => '1']],false);
    }


    return redirect()->route('document.pending');
}
```

routes:

```
Route::post('/documents/pending/approve/{id}',
[
   'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateIsApprove',
   'as' => 'document.pending',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateExistingPivot($id, array $attributes, $touch = true)
```

First parametr should be id of related thing.

Comment: Is this optional? I didn't find this anything at Laravel documentation.

Comment: It is required. Look at my example: $comany->members()->updateExistingPivot($member->id, ['is_admin' => true]);

Comment: I didn't see any wrong with your code but I tried follow but nothing happens it doesn't update into my pivot table.

Comment: Tell me what you want to do in yours method. Look at $approve - you created new instance so $approve->id is null. Same as $document. If you created new instance so it is not related with anything.

Comment: Something about yours error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException. You defined post route and you created <a href = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->id) }}">(...)</a> (GET). You should change yours route definition from post to get or create form with method="post".

Comment: I just wanted to update my `isApprove` column in my pivot table. How can I associate the approve id using `updateExistingPivot`?

Comment: I use `<a href = "{{ route ('document.pending', $list->id) }}">` to get the current id of the document. Is it possible to update without creating form?

Comment: what is the use of last parameter (`$touch`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateIsApprove($documentId, $approveId)
{
$document = Document::find($documentId);

if (!$document) {
    // Handle error that document not exists.
}

$approve = $document->sentToApprovers()->find($approveId);

if (!$approve) {
    // Handle that approve not exists or is not related with document.
}

$document->sentToApproves()->updateExistingPivot($approve->id, ['isApprove' => 1]);

return redirect()->route('document.pending');
}
```

Comment: I got an error I think I missed something? It says `Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController::updateIsApprove()` What arguments I'm missing here?

Comment: You dont have argument 2 :D You need to specify it in route.

Comment: My route look like this. `Route::get('/documents/pending/approve/{id}',
[
 'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateIsApprove',
 'as' => 'document.pending',
]);` Did I missed something?

Comment: I did tried this in this way. `/documents/pending/approve/{$documentId}/{$approveId}`. But I got a error. `Missing required parameters for [Route: document.pending] [URI: documents/pending/approve/{$documentId}/{$approveId}]`

Answer (score 0):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is not for your controller but is for your `Route`. As you can see, in your Routes file, you have Route for handling `POST` request, but in your view you are making a `GET` request by accessing the URL directly.
So, just change the `POST` route to `GET` in your Routes file.

```
Route::get('/documents/pending/approve/{id}',
[
   'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@updateIsApprove',
   'as' => 'document.pending',
]);
```